# setTimeout / clearTimeout issues, doesn't appear to reset

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout

I'm trying to create menus that drop down when hovering over the menu name.  As the names and the menu divs aren't adjacent, I needed a way to delay the menus from disappearing, so users can move from the name to the menu itself.  I used a setTimeout for this.  Once hovering on the menu, I need it to remain open until the mouse leaves, after which it should hide.

What I've tried is a complete mess.  Not sure how to fix it.  Because the setTimeout is inside the initial mouseover, the timer loops over itself... but the setTimeout doesn't seem to work if I put it anywhere else.

Here's the code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.headermenushow').mouseover(function () {
    $(this).next('.dropmenu').show(0, function () {
      timer = setTimeout(function() {
        $('.dropmenu').hide(10);
      }, 2000);
    });

    $(this).next('.dropmenu').mouseover(function () {
      clearTimeout(timer);
    });

  });
});
```

Here's an abridged jsfiddle showing how I want to use it:

http://jsfiddle.net/H247x/1/

Any help would be great.  Not really sure how to get this working better...

Comment: can you provide us a jsfiddle for that.

Comment: We need to see your HTML and understand better exactly what you're trying to accomplish.  As it stands now, it's clear that there are a number of things wrong with your current code, but not clear exactly what you're trying to do.

Comment: added jsfiddle - should demonstrate how I want to use this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are all sorts of problems with this code:

1. You are adding event handlers inside the `.mouseover()` event.  That means that every time there's a mouseover event, you add yet another set of event handlers.  These will pile up and make a real mess when the ALL execute.  You need one and only one set of event handlers for each active object.
2. Your whole logic for how this should work seems flawed.  You want a menu to stay dropped down as long as the mouse is over an item.  The mouseover event happens only when the mouse first moves onto an item.  You don't have any way to keep the menu down when the mouse is hovered over it as you just seem to blindly hide it 2 seconds after showing regardless of whether the mouse is still there or not.
3. You are using an implicit global variable for your timer.  This creates a bunch of problems.  First off, if there is more than one `.headermenushow` object, each object's `timer` will step on the others.  Second off implicit global variables are just bad and can easily lead to bugs.  Declare it exlicitly in the scope you want it in.
4. You can timers on top of timers.  Anytime you save a timer to a shared variable, you must either check for a previous timer that is already running or stop any previous timer before you overwrite it's variable.  This prevents losing track of a timer that is running and prevents stacking up multiple timers all trying to do the same thing.

We could probably help you come up with much better code, but we'd need to see your actual HTML and understand better what exactly the behavior is that you're trying to implement.

FYI, you may also want to review the CSS `:hover` selector that will let you show/hide things upon hover without any JS code at all.  Since I don't know what your HTML looks like, I can't say for sure if this would work for you, but it is used by many menuing systems is is really simple when done right.

---

Now that you've revealed your HTML, here's a version that works.  I must say that a lot of this javascript is because your HTML doesn't make this as easy as it could be.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".headermenushow").hover(function() {
        // hide any previous dropdown menus
        $(".dropmenu").hide();

        var self = $(this);
        var timer = self.data("timer");

        // show the dropdown menu for this item
        self.next().show();

        // clear any previous timer for this menu
        if (timer) {
            clearTimeout(timer);
            self.data("timer", null);
        }

    }, function() {
        // hide only on a delay so that user can move
        // to the menu
        var self = $(this);
        var menu = self.next();
        var timer = self.data("timer");
        // clear any previous timer that might have been active
        if (timer) clearTimeout(timer);
        timer = setTimeout(function() {
            self.data("timer", null);
            // if mouse is not over the menu, then hide it
            if (!menu.data("hover")) {
                menu.hide();
            }
        }, 500);
        self.data("timer", timer);

    });

    // keep track of hover state on the menu
    $(".dropmenu").hover(function() {
        $(this).data("hover", true);
    }, function() {
        $(this).data("hover", false);
        $(this).hide();
    });
});
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/YJu6Q/

Comment: yes, there are a lot of problems with my script.  I looked into CSS first, but I can't accomplish the effect I need for this.  Regarding point 2 - I realize thats a problem, but the setTimeout doesn't seem to work unless I include it inside the original event.

Comment: tried doing it without the setTimeout - just using delayed hide() and show() - but couldn't get that to work properly.  Here's the example: http://jsfiddle.net/H247x/2/

Comment: The concepts are already well explained in this answer, so i'll just leave this here: http://jsfiddle.net/H247x/4/

Comment: @user3180105 - I added a solution.  If you just made the `dropmenu` touch the `headermenushow` (so no gap between them) even if the part touching wasn't something you would see, this whole thing would be a lot, lot simpler (only a few lines of code).